# An integral that might contain a typo

Tags: calculus, integration

This is one of my homework problems, which I am unable to solve for a while:

$$\int x^8\sqrt{7+2x^5} \, dx$$

It seems the integral is not really open to an instant-solve with u-substitution, integration by part or any elementary integration techniques which a first-year calculus course presents...so am I missing something or is there a typo in this problem?

Comment: You can feel comfortable assuming this is the case given wolframalphas evaluation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E8+sqrt%287%2B2x%5E5%29

Comment: I've been tutoring calculus 1 for several years now, and this is definitely a typo.  See user11187's response.  Certainly, they will not expect knowledge of the hypergeometric function.  :P

Comment: Aha thank you! I'll go look up hypergeometric functions on Wikipedia.

Comment: The most likely typos is $7 + 2x^{\color{red}{3}}$ instead of $7 + 2x^5$

Comment: @achille hui This is very probable

Comment: @achille: integrands with $x^4$, $x^9$, $x^{14}$... instead of $x^8$ are also doable, but your interpretation is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral is $$\frac{1}{299} x^4 \left(\sqrt{2 x^5+7} \left(26 x^5+35\right)-35 \sqrt{7} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{5};\frac{9}{5};-\frac{1}{7} \left(2 x^5\right)\right)\right)$$
which is definitely not elementary. If this is from a calculus course, there has to be a typo.

Comment: I see, well sometimes Wolfram Alpha gives strangely long computation results while it can be reduced significantly...but in this case it's not elementary..definitely not..

Comment: The factor of 299 here is extremely interesting...

Comment: What do you mean..?